# Shibboleth : How to configure Inbound message processing interception with principal criteria

Tags: configuration, shibboleth, intercept, idp

I'd like to configure an intercept onto my IDP so that a user matching some specific criteria would be automatically redirected towards a static HTML page.

I succeeded to achieve that behaviour while configuring an intercept of type "Post-authentication" like this :

***/conf/relying-party.xml***

```
    <bean id="CAS.LoginConfiguration_custom" class="net.shibboleth.idp.cas.config.impl.LoginConfiguration"
            p:servletRequest-ref="shibboleth.HttpServletRequest"
            p:ticketValidityPeriod="60000"
            p:postAuthenticationFlows="regulation" />
```

**/conf/intercept/regulation-intercept-config.xml**

```
    <bean id="shibboleth.regulation.Condition" parent="shibboleth.Conditions.AND">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="net.shibboleth.idp.profile.logic.SimpleAttributePredicate" p:useUnfilteredAttributes="true">
                    <property name="attributeValueMap">
                         <map>
                             <entry key="id">
                                 <list>
                                     <value>john.doe</value>
                                 </list>
                             </entry>
                         </map>
                     </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

**But my intention is to make interception based on the Inbound message processing** (p:inboundInterceptorFlows) so that no SSO session is created since it is useless. The user would be immediately (after authentication) to the static HTML page.

I tried the following configuration ***/conf/relying-party.xml***

```
    <bean id="CAS.LoginConfiguration_custom" class="net.shibboleth.idp.cas.config.impl.LoginConfiguration"
            p:servletRequest-ref="shibboleth.HttpServletRequest"
            p:ticketValidityPeriod="60000"
            **p:inboundInterceptorFlows**="regulation" />
```

But I don't see how to configure the condition bean (from the file *regulation-intercept-config.xml*) in order to extract the principal name of the just authenticated user.
**To notice : **

- the authn/RemoteUser login flow is configured -
- The IDP receives the remote user from the Shibboleth AuthnRemoteUser servlet.

Is this possible ?

Thanks for helping me,
BR